Quarkus Maven project, ctrl click not working
I have an existing maven project done with Quarkus where ctrl click does not work (Eclipse).
eclipse.buildId=4.31.0.20240307-1200
java.version=19.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Pressing F3 returns:
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Bad zip entry: codestarts/quarkus-jbang/project/quarkus-jbang/base/..gitignore in C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\io\quarkus\quarkus-devtools-base-codestarts\2.11.3.Final\quarkus-devtools-base-codestarts-2.11.3.Final.jar

I tried deleting .project and .classpath.
I tried installing a newer version via pom.
I tried deleting .m2 folder and install again.
I tried deleting and recloning the project.
I tried deleting that jar, but Mavens will download it again.
I am out of options.
The project doesn't present any visible issues.
Error view shows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad zip entry: codestarts/quarkus-jbang/project/quarkus-jbang/base/..gitignore in C:\Users\usern\.m2\repository\io\quarkus\quarkus-devtools-base-codestarts\2.11.3.Final\quarkus-devtools-base-codestarts-2.11.3.Final.jar
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JarPackageFragmentRoot.computeChildren(JarPackageFragmentRoot.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProjectElementInfo.initializePackageNames(JavaProjectElementInfo.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProjectElementInfo.getProjectCache(JavaProjectElementInfo.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProjectElementInfo.newNameLookup(JavaProjectElementInfo.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.newNameLookup(JavaProject.java:2808)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.<init>(SearchableEnvironment.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.<init>(SearchableEnvironment.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CancelableNameEnvironment.<init>(CancelableNameEnvironment.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CancelableNameEnvironment.<init>(CancelableNameEnvironment.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnitResolver.resolve(CompilationUnitResolver.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.internalCreateASTCached(ASTParser.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.lambda$0(ASTParser.java:1120)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.cacheZipFiles(JavaModelManager.java:5839)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.internalCreateAST(ASTParser.java:1120)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createAST(ASTParser.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation.CoreASTProvider$1.run(CoreASTProvider.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation.CoreASTProvider.createAST(CoreASTProvider.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation.CoreASTProvider.getAST(CoreASTProvider.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation.SharedASTProviderCore.getAST(SharedASTProviderCore.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup.calculateASTandInform(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup$1.lambda$0(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.cacheZipFiles(JavaModelManager.java:5839)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.callReadOnly(JavaModelManager.java:5828)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.callReadOnly(JavaCore.java:6126)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup$1.run(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

POM file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>company</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <failsafe.useModulePath>false</failsafe.useModulePath>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>2.11.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-mongodb-panache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-devtools-common</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.smallrye.reactive</groupId>
            <artifactId>smallrye-mutiny-vertx-web-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <skipITs>false</skipITs>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>


Can you try to remove the directory C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\io\quarkus\quarkus-devtools-base-codestarts and rebuild?  It's rare but I've seen that once in a while something happens during the download of a file through Maven and this happens.

@stdunbar I did as you suggested, unfortunately I still have the same problem.
